Degenerate perturbation theory to nonlinear equation
I want to use perturbation theory to find the steady-state solution to the following nonlinear equation:
$$
x_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^Nx_j^2\right)-a x_i + \epsilon \sum_{j\neq i}^N J_{ij}x_j=0,
$$
where $i=1\cdots N$ and $\epsilon$ is a small parameters. To apply perturbation theory, we expand $x_i = x_i^{(0)} + \epsilon x_i^{(1)} + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2) $.

The zeroth order solution is given by
$$
\sum_{i}\left[x_{i}^{\left(0\right)}\right]^{2} = a,
$$
which gives a degenerate of solutions.
Expanding it to first order in $\epsilon$ gives
$$
2 (x_i^{(0)})^2 x_i^{(1)} + 2x_i^{(0)}\sum_{j\neq i}x_j^{(0)}x_j^{(1)} + \sum_{j\neq i}J_{ij}x^{(0)}_j=0 ,
$$
but then the solution to $x_i^{(1)}$ involves other $x_j^{(1)}$.

I think this issue arises because we have a degenerate of solutions to the unperturbed equation.
Is there a way to apply degenerate perturbation theory to obtain an
explicit form for $x_i^{(1)}$ ?.



I'm interested in seeing how the perturbations lift the degeneracy of solutions.

What is the problem with "but then the solution to (1) involves other (1)"? What you get here is a linear system, which can be written on the form $Ax^{(1)} = b$, for the $x_j^{(1)}$'s that you have to solve. This system should generally have a solution (meaning $\det A \not= 0$ in most cases).

Did you try the Adomian method? See http://www.globalscientificjournal.com/researchpaper/SOLVING_NONLINEAR_SYSTEM_OF_EQUATIONS_USING_THE_ADOMIAN_DECOMPOSITION_METHOD.pdf

Rewrite the system of equations in the following clearer form:
$$
\vec{x}\left[\left(|x|^{2}-a\right)I+\epsilon J\right]=0.
$$
Then there are 2 possible cases

$\left[\left(|x|^{2}-a\right)I+\epsilon J\right]=0.$ This only occurs at $\epsilon =0$ and the solution $|x|^2 =a$ coincides with your original solution, and

$\left[\left(|x|^{2}-a\right)I+\epsilon J\right]$ has a zero eigenvectior, and then $\vec x$ is proportional to it. This can be acheived by setting  setting $|x|^2-a =-\epsilon\lambda$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $J$. At $\epsilon=0$ the solution reverts to the unperturbed problem, but $\vec x$ is again degenerate.


So as long as one can find such an eigenvalue, a second "$\epsilon$" dependent solution exists.
